# How to rebuild database from queries

Tags: mysql, sql

My task is to rebuild database structure from queries found in code, these are queries that I have found:

Query 1:

```
Select      o.id, n.nazwa, n.nazwa, n.typ, o.kwota, o.pozostala_kwota, o.pozostale_raty
from        oplaty          o
inner join  wlasciciel      w   on  w.id = o.id_wlasciciela
inner join  nieruchomosc    n   on  n.id = o.id_nieruchomosci
where       w.dane_osobowe = ? 
and         o.rok = ?
```

Query 2:

```
Select      n.id, n.powierzchnia, n.nazwa, n.typ, wn.procent_posiadania
from        wlasciciele_nieruchomosci   wn
inner join  wlasciciel                  w   on  w.id = wn.id_wlasciciela
inner join  nieruchomosc                n   on  n.id = wn.id_nieruchomosci
where       w.id = ?
```

What does this notations mean:

`select o.id` - why is there a dot and what `o` stands for?

`wlasciciel w` - i know `wlascicel` is table name but what does`w` stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After table name `oplaty` you have alias `o` and expression `select o.id` means that you want to select `id` from table with `o` alias so it'll be `id`from table `oplaty`.
You can use alias with the key word 'AS' or without.
For more informations see page: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score 3):

The "o" and the "w" are simply aliases for the table name.  At this point, I'd say you need to take time on an SQL Tutorial, such as: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/.

Answer (score 2):

Those are aliases. o represents the table oplaty, while w represents the table wlasciciel.

Answer (score 0):

w is a shortening for wlasciciel

o.id = SELECT id FROM oplaty